# ¿Como puedo integrar un FPDF con mi consulta a la base de datos?

Tags: php, fpdf

Gracias a la ayuda de los miembros de SO he logrado hacer la consulta a base de datos y además logre hacer funcionar mi FPDF de manera correcta pero por separado,si quisiera hacer que esta consulta

```
<?php
    $TIPO_BUSQUEDA = $_POST["TIPO_BUSQUEDA"];
    function ejecuta_consulta($labusqueda)
    {
        include("conexiond.php");

        $conexion= mysqli_connect($db_host, $db_usuario, $db_contra);

        if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
            echo "Fallo al conectar con la base de datos";
            exit();
        }

        mysqli_select_db($conexion, $db_nombre) or die("No se encuentra la base de datos.");


        $consulta = "SELECT datosbasicos.CED_PAC,datosbasicos.NOM_PAC,datosbasicos.APE_PAC,datosbasicos.SEX_PAC,datosmedicos.COD_CONSULTA,datosmedicos.ALT_PAC,datosmedicos.PESO_PAC,datosmedicos.FECHA,datosmedicos.TIPO_CONSULTA,datosmedicos.SINTOMAS,datosmedicos.OBSERV,datosmedicos.HIS_PAC,datosmedicos.MEDI_PAC,datosmedicos.OPERADO,datosmedicos.ALERGIAS FROM datosbasicos INNER JOIN datosmedicos ON datosbasicos.CED_PAC=datosmedicos.CED_PAC WHERE datosbasicos.NOM_PAC LIKE '%$labusqueda%' OR datosbasicos.CED_PAC LIKE '%$labusqueda%' OR datosmedicos.COD_CONSULTA LIKE '%$labusqueda%' OR datosbasicos.CED_PAC LIKE '%$labusqueda%' OR datosmedicos.FECHA LIKE '%$labusqueda%'  ";

        $resultados = mysqli_query($conexion, $consulta);

        $filas = array(); // Crea la variable $filas y se le asigna un array vacío
        // (Si la consulta no devuelve ningún resultado, la función por lo menos va a retornar un array vacío)

        while ($fila=mysqli_fetch_array($resultados, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
            $filas[] = $fila; // Añade el array $fila al final de $filas
        }

        mysqli_close($conexion);

        return $filas; // Devuelve el array $filas
    }
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Sistema de historias médicas - Dr. Darling Davila</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/estilo.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato|Roboto" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
    <?php
        $mibusqueda=$_GET["buscar"];

        $mipag=$_SERVER["PHP_SELF"];

        if ($mibusqueda!=null) {
            $pacientes = ejecuta_consulta($mibusqueda);
    ?>

        <div id="main-container">
        <img src='imagenes/header.png' class='img'>
            <table>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Codigo Consulta</th>
                        <th>Fecha</th>
                        <th>Cedula</th>
                        <th>Nombres</th>
                        <th>Apellidos</th>
                        <th>Sexo</th>
                        <th>Altura</th>
                        <th>Peso</th>
                        <th>Sintomas</th>
                        <th>Observaciones</th>
                        <th>Tipo de consulta</th>
                        <th>Medicamentos actuales</th>
                        <th>Alergias</th>
                        <th>Operado</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <?php
                    // Si la variable $pacientes esta definida y no está vacía
                    if (isset($pacientes) && !empty($pacientes)) {
                        // Recorre cada $paciente dentro del array $pacientes
                        foreach ($pacientes as $paciente) {
                            ?>
                        <tr>
                            <td><?php echo $paciente['COD_CONSULTA'] ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $paciente['FECHA'] ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $paciente['CED_PAC'] ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $paciente['NOM_PAC'] ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $paciente['APE_PAC'] ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $paciente['SEX_PAC'] ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $paciente['ALT_PAC'] ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $paciente['PESO_PAC'] ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $paciente['SINTOMAS'] ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $paciente['OBSERV'] ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $paciente['TIPO_CONSULTA'] ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $paciente['MEDI_PAC'] ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $paciente['ALERGIAS'] ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $paciente['OPERADO'] ?></td>
                        </tr>
                    <?php
                        }
                    } ?>
                </tbody>
        </div>
    <?php
        } else {
            echo("<form action='". $mipag . "' method='GET'>
                <img src='imagenes/header.png'>
                    <h2>Busqueda de paciente</h2>
                    <div class='contenedor'>
                    <select name='TIPO_BUSQUEDA' class='input-100 text-center col-md-12'>
                        <option value='Cedula' selected='selected' <?PHP if($TIPO_BUSQUEDA=='Cedula'){ echo 'selected='selected'; } ?> Cedula</option>
                        <option value='Edad' <?PHP if($TIPO_BUSQUEDA=='Edad'){ echo 'selected='selected'; } ?> Edad</option>
                        <option value='Nombre' <?PHP if($TIPO_BUSQUEDA=='Nombre'){ echo 'selected='selected'; } ? >Nombre</option>
                        <option value='Fecha' <?PHP if($TIPO_BUSQUEDA=='Fecha'){ echo 'selected='selected'; } ?> Fecha</option>
                    </select>
                    <input type='text' name='buscar' class='input-100 text-center inline-block col-md-6 btn-enviar espacio-arriba'></label>

                    <input type='submit' name='enviando' value='Consulta' class='text-center inline-block col-md-12 espacio-arriba btn-enviar'>
                </div>
                </form>");
        }
     ?>

</body>

</html>
```

Me permita imprimir en PDF lo que arroje la consulta ¿Como haria? pues tengo el codigo de FPDF pero haciendo una consulta general que no me permite segun lo que yo busque, para ello se que debo tener el boton adicional en el primer formulario donde me mmuestra la consulta el cual me diga algo como " Imprimir " y ahi me lo genere en PDF.

**EDIT**

Ya he hecho el boton que me genera el PDF el cual es el siguiente

```html
<form name="reporte" action="database.php" method="post">
        <input type='submit' name='generar' value='PDF' class='text-center inline-block col-md-12 espacio-arriba btn-enviar2'>
        </form>
        </div>
```

Pero ahora no logro hacer que en este codigo me tome la variables que ya tenia en la consulta para que me las lleve a PDF.

**Codigo FPDF**

```
<?php
require('tfpdf.php');
$con=mysqli_connect('localhost','root','12345678');
mysqli_select_db($con,'pacientes');


class PDF extends TFPDF {
    function Header(){
        $this->SetFont('Arial','B',15);

        //dummy cell to put logo
        //$this->Cell(12,0,'',0,0);
        //is equivalent to:
        $this->Cell(12);

        //put logo
        $this->Image('imagenes/header.png',150,10,60);

        $this->Cell(1,50,'Lista de pacientes',0,1);

        //dummy cell to give line spacing
        //$this->Cell(0,5,'',0,1);
        //is equivalent to:
        $this->Ln(5);
        $this->SetFont('Arial','B',11);

        $this->SetFillColor(54,150,129);
        $this->SetDrawColor(36,99,85);
        $this->Cell(40,5,'Nombre ',1,0,'',true);
        $this->Cell(40,5,'Apellido',1,0,'',true);
        $this->Cell(25,5,'Edad',1,0,'',true);
        $this->Cell(25,5,'Sexo',1,0,'',true);
        $this->Cell(30,5,'Telefono',1,0,'',true);
        $this->Cell(30,5,'Celular',1,0,'',true);
        $this->Cell(130,5,'Direccion',1,1,'',true);


    }
    function Footer(){
        //add table's bottom line
        $this->Cell(190,0,'','T',1,'',true);

        //Go to 1.5 cm from bottom
        $this->SetY(-15);

        $this->SetFont('Arial','',8);

        //width = 0 means the cell is extended up to the right margin
        $this->Cell(0,10,'Page '.$this->PageNo()." / {pages}",0,0,'C');
    }
}


//A4 width : 219mm
//default margin : 10mm each side
//writable horizontal : 219-(10*2)=189mm


$pdf = new PDF('L','mm',array(400,200)); //use new class

//define new alias for total page numbers
$pdf->AliasNbPages('{pages}');

$pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(true,15);
$pdf->AddPage();

$pdf->SetFont('Arial','',9);
$pdf->SetDrawColor(36,99,85);

// Add a Unicode font (uses UTF-8)
$pdf->AddFont('Arial','','Arial.ttf',true);
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','',11);

$query=mysqli_query($con,"select * from datosbasicos");
while($data=mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
    $pdf->Cell(40,5,$data['NOM_PAC'],'LR',0);
    $pdf->Cell(40,5,$data['APE_PAC'],'LR',0);
    $pdf->Cell(25,5,$data['EDAD_PAC'],'LR',0);
    $pdf->Cell(25,5,$data['SEX_PAC'],'LR',0);
    $pdf->Cell(30,5,$data['TEL_PAC'],'LR',0);
    $pdf->Cell(30,5,$data['CEL_PAC'],'LR',0);
    $pdf->Cell(130,5,$data['DIR_PAC'],'LR',0);

    if($pdf->GetStringWidth($data['email']) > 65){
        $pdf->SetFont('Arial','',7);
        $pdf->Cell(65,5,$data['email'],'LR',0);
        $pdf->SetFont('Arial','',9);
    }else{
        $pdf->Cell(65,5,$data['email'],'LR',0);
    }
    $pdf->Cell(60,5,$data['address'],'LR',1);
}














$pdf->Output();
?>
```

Comment: ¿Alguna opinion al respecto? He estado probando pero aun no logro que funcione.

Answer (score 0):

Si lo que quieres hacer es como un historial con los datos del paciente podrias hacer una plantilla

```
$plantilla .= ('
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td> Nombre del paciente: '. $data['nombre_paciente'] .' </td>
                    <td> Nombre del paciente: '. $data['apellido_paciente'] .' </td>
                    <td> Nombre del paciente: '. $data['edad_paciente'] .' </td>
                    <td> Nombre del paciente: '. $data['telefono_paciente'] .' </td> 
                </tr>
            </table>
          ');
//Al final de armarla copias WriteHTML
$pdf->WriteHTML($plantilla);
```

Comment: Lo que quiero es que los datos arrojados de la consulta pueda imprimirlos luego en PDF (Es decir, que los pueda ver en pagina y luego si quiero imprimirlos)

Comment: Cuando generas la consulta, envia por post o get el id del paciente a el documento el cual genera el pdf, rescatalo y realiza tu consulta nuevamente con el parametro que enviastes

Comment: No te sirve la respuesta que te publique mas arriba con un ejemplo?

Answer (score 0):

te dejo un ejemplo del archivo fpdf de una manera en que yo había realizado lo que intentas hacer. Espero te sirva de algo. Las consultas las realizo directamente en este archivo para visualizar y si así deseas puedes imprimirlo. Te lo copio así para que puedas visualizarlo. Saludos.

```html
<?php

require_once 'funciones.php';
require('fpdf/fpdf.php');
//include 'menu.php';
$link = conectarse();
session_start();
ob_start();

$estado = $_GET['estado'];
$numero=0;


//Conecto a la base de datos
$enlace = mysql_connect("localhost", "root");
 
mysql_select_db("edwin", $enlace);
//Consulta la tabla productos solicitando todos los productos
 
class PDF extends FPDF {

    function Header() {
        $this->Image('images/icono.png', 5,-1, 38);
        $this->SetFont('Arial', 'B', 20);
        $this->Cell(25);
        $this->Cell(150, 10, utf8_decode('CLÍNICA DE RUNNING 2019'), 0, 0, 'C');
        $this->Ln(25);
    }

    function Footer() {
        
        $this->SetY(-15);
        $this->SetFont('Arial', 'I', 8);
        $this->Cell(0, 10, 'Pagina ' . $this->PageNo(), 0, 0, 'C');
    }

}

switch ($estado) {
    case 'TODOS':
        $resultado = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM persona_has_evento INNER JOIN persona ON persona_has_evento.even_pers_id=persona.pers_id WHERE persona_has_evento.EVENTO_even_id=1 ORDER BY persona.pers_apel ASC", $link);
        break;
    case 'Pagado':
        $resultado = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM persona_has_evento INNER JOIN persona ON persona_has_evento.even_pers_id=persona.pers_id WHERE (persona_has_evento.EVENTO_even_id=1) AND (persona.pers_comp_pago=1) ORDER BY persona.pers_apel ASC", $link);
        break;
    case 'No-pago':
        $resultado = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM persona_has_evento INNER JOIN persona ON persona_has_evento.even_pers_id=persona.pers_id WHERE (persona_has_evento.EVENTO_even_id=1) AND (persona.pers_comp_pago IS NULL) ORDER BY persona.pers_apel ASC", $link);
        break;
}

//Instaciamos la clase para genrear el documento pdf
$pdf=new PDF();
 
//Agregamos la primera pagina al documento pdf
$pdf->AddPage();
 

 
//Creamos las celdas para los titulo de cada columna y le asignamos un fondo gris y el tipo de letra
$pdf->SetFillColor(232,232,232);
 
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',10);
$pdf->Cell(190, 6, utf8_decode('LISTADO DE PARTICIPANTES CLÍNICA DE RUNNING 2019           ESTADO:'.$estado), 1, 1, 'C'); //RENGLON PARA FECHA Y ESTADO
$pdf->Cell(190, 6, '', 1, 1, 'C'); //renglon en blanco
$pdf->Cell(10,6,'Nro.',1,0,'C',1);
$pdf->Cell(30,6,'Apellido',1,0,'C',1);
$pdf->Cell(30,6,'Nombre',1,0,'C',1);
$pdf->Cell(20,6,'DNI',1,0,'C',1);
$pdf->Cell(20,6,'Fecha Nac.',1,0,'C',1);
$pdf->Cell(30,6,'Telefono',1,0,'C',1);
$pdf->Cell(50,6,'Email',1,0,'C',1);
 
$pdf->Ln(10);
 
//Comienzo a crear las filas de productos según la consulta mysql con los nombres de la base de datos
 
while($fila = mysql_fetch_array($resultado))
{
    $numero = $numero + 1;
    $nombre = $fila['pers_nomb'];
    $apellido = $fila['pers_apel'];
    $dni=$fila['pers_dni'];
    $fechanac= date("d/m/Y", strtotime($fila['pers_fecnac']));
    $telefono=$fila['pers_tel'];
    $email=$fila['pers_email'];
 
   //125 
    $pdf->SetFont('Arial','',8);
    $pdf->Cell(10,5,$numero,1,0,'L',0);
    $pdf->Cell(30,5,$apellido,1,0,'L',0);
    $pdf->Cell(30,5,$nombre,1,0,'L',0);       
    $pdf->Cell(20,5,$dni,1,0,'L',0);
    $pdf->Cell(20,5,$fechanac,1,0,'L',0);
    $pdf->Cell(30,5,$telefono,1,0,'L',0);
    $pdf->Cell(50,5,$email,1,0,'L',0);
//Muestro la iamgen dentro de la celda GetX y GetY dan las coordenadas actuales de la fila
 
     //$pdf->Cell( 30, 15, $pdf->Image($imagen, $pdf->GetX()+5, $pdf->GetY()+3, 20), 1, 0, 'C', false );
 
$pdf->Ln(5);
 
}
 
mysql_close($enlace);
 
//Mostramos el documento pdf
$pdf->Output();
 






?>
```